# ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool doesn't work with log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I have an asp.net website that uses log4net. Log4net is configured in Global.asx like this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
    // ...
}
```

But then the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool only shows me this error:

```
 An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.
```

When I comment the log4net configuration, the Web Administration Tool starts working normally.

Is there a way to make them work nice with each other?

**EDIT:**

I managed to get the WSAT work by wrapping the log4net configuration in a try/catch:

```
try
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

However the trace doesn't appear on the output window so I can't tell what exception it is exactly.

Comment: Turn on [breaking when an exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) and you might be able to see what's going on

Comment: @stuartd can that be turned on for the WSAT? I've tried enabling it in all the categories but it still shows the same error. WSAT runs on it's own separate Development Server so I don't think Visual Studio starts it with debugging enabled.

Comment: I wonder if the log4net config is invalid. Can you post your config file?

Comment: The Log4net configuration is ok and it works fine with the actual site. But I wonder if the WSAT server is using a different config file and that's why it fails.

Comment: Log4net will never throw an exception by design so it won't complain if there's no config in the config file. You could try moving the lof4net config to its own file